# unable able to create table in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, bigdata

When i try to create table in HIVE using below command,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( eid int, name String,
salary String, destination String)
COMMENT 'Employee details'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I get below error.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)
```

I have give full permission to /user/hive/warehouse directory in HDFS.

Comment: please share  hive-site.xml  file ,it looks like your hive metastore is not setup properly.

Comment: can you add full exception logtrace into question from hive logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

I have found the solution.
I am using HIVE 2.1.0.

Its mandatory to initialize the schema with SCHEMA TOOL

Comand:
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema

Note: In my case -dbType is mysql since I use mysql as rdbms.

please refer the below link:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool

I Have dropped the metastore db in mysql and created metastore schema by running the above mentioned command.

Now I am able to create the table in hive.

Comment: Yes. It should get initialized with schema tool.